# jQuery validation not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Below is my `regular expression` method.

```
 $.validator.addMethod("regex", function (element, value, regexp) {
        var re = new RegExp(regexp);
        return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
    }, "Special Characters not permitted");
```

Below is my `rules`.

```
var rules = {
    cname: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 8
        //alphanumeric:true
        //regex: "/^\w+$/i"
        //uniqueCompnameName: true
    }
}
```

When i pass the regular expression to regex, it does not work at all.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or jsbin ? A link to the plugin you're using would be nice too.

Comment: your regex param is wrong... it should be just `'^\w+$'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So keep in mind that `\w` is going to be the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Now, for the Regex, you are really looking for this here:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]{8,}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

That's saying any word character with a minimum length of 8 characters.

And then finally, when passing the Regex into the function, you want to pass it like this:

```
regex: '^[A-Za-z0-9]{8,}$'
```

and then when building the `RegExp` you want to pass the flags as the second parameter:

```
var re = new RegExp(regexp, 'i');
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ZcuElRAMf5kdr9LN)

Comment: I am actually looking for a regular expression which won't allow special characters

Comment: Can u just tell me, whats wrong here. regex: "^[0-9]{10,}$" when allowing only numbers.

Comment: @theJava, it doesn't appear there is anything wrong with that Regex, but if you're having problems, post a new question with *all of the details.*

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass the regex using a regex notation instead as a string

```
$.validator.addMethod("regexp", function (value, element, regexp) {
    if (typeof regexp == 'string') {
        regexp = new RegExp(regexp);
    }
    return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);
}, "Special Characters not permitted");
```

then

```
        name1: {
            required: true,
            regexp: '/^\w+$/'
        },
        name2: {
            required: true,
            regexp: /^\w+$/i
        }
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LpF4a/)